# math.floor doesn't round the number

Tags: python

I tried to do a code for testing some things like the floor and ceil functions but something goes wrong, here is the code:

```
import random
import math

difficolty = 3
healt = 50
potion_healt = random.randint(20,50)/3

healt = healt + potion_healt

if difficolty < 3:
   math.ceil(healt)

else:
   math.floor(healt)

print(f"You have {healt} ps!")
```

Even if i used the math.floor function the output is this:

```
You have 63.666666666666664 ps!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If i set the difficulty to 1 or 2 the code output is not like that.

Comment: `ceil` and `floor` return the result. You are ignoring the return values.

Comment: ... and they don't change the value in-place, so it should be `healt = math.floor(healt)`

Comment: To be fair: I never understand why PL's cannot be created in such a way that they generate an error for methods where the return value is ignored while they don't generate side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reassign the output of **math.floor** / **math.ceil** to the variable health.

Fixed version:

```
import random
import math

difficolty = 3
healt = 50
potion_healt = random.randint(20,50)/3

healt = healt + potion_healt

if difficolty < 3:
   # reassign value to healt
   healt = math.ceil(healt)

else:
   # reassign value to healt
   healt = math.floor(healt)

print(f"You have {healt} ps!")
```

Besides that: you should work on your english a bit, as correct pronuciation of variable names is fundamental for maintaining large codebases with other contributors.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `math.ceil` nor `math.floor` will change its argument. Instead, you need to assign the return value to a variable (the same you pass in, or another one, depending on what you are trying to do).